# how to create schema for similar data for different areas

Tags: mysql, schema

I have to create tables to store weather for different areas for different entities. What is the best way to create table structure for this. For example:

```
maximum temp for Wales  
year jan feb  
1950 0.5 2.5   
1955 1.   2  
.  
.  

2017 0.5 2  


minimum temp for Wales  
year jan feb  
1995  -5 -7
.  
.  
2018 -8  -9
```

is it better to create multiple tables for each city for different recording or is there a better way.

Comment: This is so wrong. Please read a tutorial on table design. You are violating almost all design rules.

Comment: this is how the data looks, what is the best way to create a table structure

Answer (score 1):

```
areas table
-----------
id
name


temperatures table
------------------
id
area_id
year
month
min_temp
max_temp
```

Comment: I would keep year and month as a single entity (which , combined with area_id, *could* also be the PK)